# extjs vtype: check value using another value in the same row

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have an `Ext.grid.Panel` and i want to validate user input: there is a field named `delete` and a field named `string`. Valid input for `delete` is a number, which can't be greater than the length of a `string` field in the same row. I already know how to use `vtype` so now i have

```
delete : function(val, field){
            var expr = new RegExp("^[-]?[0-9]*[\.]?[0-9]*$");
            var num = expr.test(val);
            if (!num) return false; //can't be not a number
            else{
                 //have no idea...
            }
        }
```

I have no idea how to access `string` value for the same row.

Hope it's quite clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should handle `validateedit( Ext.grid.plugin.Editing editor, Object e, Object eOpts )` [event](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing-event-validateedit).

The second argument, `e`, contains reference to the record that is edited (`e.record`). You could use this record to get both fields(`string` and `delete`) and perform validation accordingly.
Assigning `false` to `e.cancel` will cancel the editing.

Comment: thanks. but i've got a problem using it: my `e.record.data[...]` stores an old, not edited value. how can i access the edited value?

Comment: so, you are correct, but there's a bug in Ext: *EXTJSIV-2550*, i'm not the only one to face this issue... http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?136911-validateedit-event-does-not-return-the-newly-entered-value

Answer (score 1):

It's actually much simpler and cleaner if you define your editor as a variable, you can just refer to it in the fields validator method and get the active record, for example:

```
// create editor as a variable
var cellEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
    clicksToEdit: 1,
    autoCancel: false
});

// referring to the edited record in the validator function
    {
        xtype: 'datecolumn',
        header: 'Comp Date',
        dataIndex: 'comp_date',
        width: 100,
        format: 'j-M-Y',
        editor: {
            xtype: 'datefield',
            format: 'j-M-Y',
            validator: function(value) {
                var record  = cellEditing.getActiveRecord(); // get active record
                if (Ext.Date.parse(value, 'j-M-Y') < record.get('start_date')) {
                    return 'Cannot complete before start date';
                } else return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

well, there's a workaround, but it's ugly:

```
rowEditing.on({
    scope : this,
    afteredit : function(roweditor, changes, record, rowIndex) {
        var can_save = true;
        var records = store.getRange();
        for(var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
            if(records[i].data['delete'] >= records[i].data['string '].toString().length) {
                Ext.MessageBox.alert('Input error', "blahblah");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I accessed the plugin the following way:

```
this.ownerCt.ownerCmp.plugins
```

That gives you access to the cellEditing plugin and from there you could do a:

```
var record = plugin.getActiveRecord();
```